# How to join spark rdd using between join?

Tags: spark-streaming

I want to join two rdd's using a between join using a column `_id` and with a timestamp column

can you tell me how I an achieve it using spark?

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Sample input data and structure. What have you tried till now?